# How to update a message created with Incoming Webhook

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm using Incoming Webhook in order to post messages into a room. Recently I discovered that there's an [API](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/update) which allows to update a message.

However when I try to make an update, the request fails with `UNAUTHENTICATED` status.

According to documentation I must have `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot` scope in order to create and update messages and since I'm able to create message I assume I have correct scope? Or is there anything else I need to do?

I do not obtain any credentials manually, I just copy the URL which is returned when Incoming Webhook is created which already contains `key` and `token` parameters.

Here's an example update request which I'm trying to make:

```sh
curl -X PUT \
     -H "Content-type: application/json" \
     --data @notifications2.json \
    "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/some-space/messages/some-message?key=some-key&token=some-token"
```

Similar request works fine when I'm creating new message:

```sh
curl -X POST \
     -H "Content-type: application/json" \
     --data @notifications2.json \
    "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/some-space/messages?key=some-key&token=some-token"
```

Am I missing some configuration or is there some limitation which doesn't allow to do that?